# Is an implementation of the let* operator included with OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, monads

So called "let operators" are [now supported](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/distrib/ocaml-4.08/ocaml-4.08-refman.html#s%3Abinding-operators) in OCaml, however I was wondering if a default implementation of `let*` and `and*`, for monads, are shipped with the standard library in a module somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not defined directly, but you can "import" them as:

```
let (let*) = Option.bind

let editor_home =
  let* home = Sys.getenv_opt "HOME" in 
  let* editor = Sys.getenv_opt "EDITOR" in 
  Some (editor ^ " " ^ home)
```

Comment: Oh, neat. The [`Option` module](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Option.html) is also new in 4.08.. Any reason why there was no `Stdlib.let*` as an alias for this?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but I wouldn't be happy to have `Option.bind` as `Stdlib.(let*)`, making it some kind of "default" monad. Having `Option.(let*)` is another, ahem, option, but would that work well? Doing `open Option` would pollute the namespace, sou you're left with `let (let*) = Option.(let*)` which is no different than `let (let*) = Option.bind`, I think. Maybe put it into `Option.Let_syntax.(let*)` or something, similar to the `ppx_let` convention. I am quite happy as-is with "importing" bind, in fact.

Comment: I suspect type-specific `Syntax` modules will start showing up in the standard library soon-ish.

Comment: I can understand the namespace pollution concern, but take for eg. `Array` and `List`, same issue there and let/bind operators could actually all have type-specific names like `let+`, `let@`, etc.